# maximum function in R removes decimals

Tags: r, dataframe, function, max, decimal-point

I have a question according to the max function in R. I have a column in a dataframe which has 2 decimals after the comma and whenever I apply the max function on the column i will get the highest value but with only 1 decimal after the comma.

```
max(df$e)
```

How can I get two decimals after the comma? I tried using options() and round() but nothing works.

Reproducible example:

```
a = c(228, 239)
b = c(50,83)
d = c(0.27,0.24) 
e = c(2.12,1.69)
df = data.frame(a,b,d,e)

max(df$e)
#[1] 2.1

df
#   a    b    d   e
# 1 228 50 0.27 2.1
# 2 239 83 0.24 1.7
```

Now I would like to make more calculations:

```
df$f = (sqrt(df[,1]/(df[,2]+0.5))/max(df$e))*100
```

In the end the dataframe should have column `a` and `b` without decimals and `d` , `e` and `f` with two decimals after the comma.

Thank you!

Comment: `format(round(max(L$SQRT), 2), nsmall = 2)`

Comment: That worked, but I wanted it as a numeric value to make further calculations with it. Now its a string. When I apply as.numeric i will get 2.1 again

Comment: `as.numeric(format(round(max(L$SQRT), 2), nsmall = 2))`

Comment: When I apply as.numeric it is just one decimal after the comma instead of two

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example   <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example>

Comment: If your column/values is numeric, then you printing options are the only thing controlling how many decimals will print. The data that is there is unchanged. If you want trailing zeroes to print, then  you may need to convert it to a string for printing.

Comment: But why for example is column `d` with two decimals and column `e` with one in the dataframe?

Comment: Hard to know - when I copy/paste your example in to my R session I see two digits for d and e, and 5 digits on f. Maybe show your `sessionInfo()` and `getOption("digits")`? Maybe restart R and see if you get the rounding in a fresh R session?

Comment: I will say that "always 2 digits after the decimal point" isn't an option I know of in base R. You can experiment with, e.g., `print(df, digits = 3)`, `print(df, digits = 5)`. But if you want to have fine control over what prints, converting to strings with `format` or `formatC` is the way to get it, at the loss of your `numeric` class.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** you've probably got `options(digits = 2)`.

```r
df
    a  b    d    e
1 228 50 0.27 2.12
2 239 83 0.24 1.69
```

If I set `options(digits = 2)` then R uses this value to set the **output** format (it doesn't change the actual values), globally, to two **significant digits** — this is "total digits", not "digits after the decimal point".

```r
options(digits = 2)
df
    a  b    d   e   f
1 228 50 0.27 2.1 100
2 239 83 0.24 1.7  80
```

To restore the value to the default, use `options(digits = 7)`.

After restoring the default `digits` setting and computing `df$f = (sqrt(df[,1]/(df[,2]+0.5))/max(df$e))*100` I get

```r
    a  b    d    e        f
1 228 50 0.27 2.12 100.2273
2 239 83 0.24 1.69  79.8031
```

You can round the last column to two decimal places:

```r
df$f <- round(df$f, 2)
> df
    a  b    d    e      f
1 228 50 0.27 2.12 100.23
2 239 83 0.24 1.69  79.80
```